# iframe autoheight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've searched everywhere including here and haven't been able to come up with a good solution. I ran into this and it works in everybrowser except Firefox and IE :( Help?

```
jQuery(function() {
    sizeIFrame();
    jQuery("#ifrm").load(sizeIFrame);
});

function sizeIFrame() { 
    var videoBrowser = jQuery("#ifrm");
    var innerDoc = videoBrowser.get(0).contentDocument ?
        videoBrowser.get(0).contentDocument.documentElement :
        videoBrowser.get(0).contentWindow.document.body;
    videoBrowser.height(35);
    videoBrowser.height(innerDoc.scrollHeight + 35);
}
```

and it's on the same domain and here's my `<iframe>`

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="http://localhost:8080/linkconsulting/temp.html" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I'm testing on `localhost` right now but it will still be on same domain later.

Update:
So I've noticed that this is not working because it seems to be interfering with tiny.scrollbar plugin or viceversa.  Not sure what to do here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up taking a different approach.  I got the contents from inside the iframe and inserted them inside a div.  Here's the code in case anyone else needs it..  Thank you all for your patience and great help.

```
<script>
function getFile(){

var content = jQuery('#servercontent')[0];

var ifrm = jQuery('#ifrm')[0];

content.innerHTML = ifrm.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;

}
</script>
<body>
 <div id="servercontent"></div>
 <iframe id="ifrm" src="webinsamedomain.com" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display:none;"  onload="getFile();" ></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that this isn't working because the height is being calculated before the document has loaded. If you were to call sizeIFrame in the document.ready event it might make a difference.

In your IFrame try this code:

```
jQuery(function(){
   parent.sizeIFrame();
}
```

Update:
As per our chat, you can get the height of the document in the IFrame with:

```
parent.jQuery(document).height()
```

I would say to pass the height as a parameter to your function.

Comment: in IE i got an error 

    Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 01:36:12 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 7
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/linkconsulting/temp.html


Message: Object expected
Line: 7
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/linkconsulting/temp.html

Comment: jQuery(function(){   I get the feeling I'm forgetting a jquery reference...hehe

Comment: @Andres in that case you could use <body onload="parent.sizeIFrame();">

Comment: now i get Object Required at Line 36 and on that line is this: videoBrowser.height(innerDoc.scrollHeight + 35);

Comment: @Andres join me in JavaScript chat.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery, try using the 
[iFrameAutoHeight plugin](https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height)

Comment: ok so I tried that aswell and still no content on IE 8 chrome yes